# Adding conditional Statement to current query

Tags: php, mysql

I am drawing information from one table to populate another. In order to complete the table, I need to include a different table and use a conditional statement

Essentially - If vat=Y then x=1.2 else x=0. (calculating tax)

I have a fiddle Here with the tables...

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrWFdhjvCYZiALS4tqhyNo/25

So then I need to get the value for `vat` which I then need to multiply with `pay` to get a total

so for example `if vat=Y and pay = 100 then vat*pay = 1.2*100 = 120`

I have tried:

```
SELECT driver.*, COUNT(add_job.Input) AS counter, SUM((CASE WHEN vat=Y then 1.2 * vat Else 0))
FROM driver
LEFT JOIN add_job ON add_job.Input = driver.DataA
GROUP BY driver.ID
```

This is one situation, the other situation is where I need to pull the vat registered details from a different table.

Any help solving this would be great

Comment: You forgot `end` in your `case..when` and replace `vat` with `pay` in the query. There you go: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrWFdhjvCYZiALS4tqhyNo/26

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Can I ask, How would i adapt that code to fit in a 3rd table? So that I can take all the entries from `add_job` which relate to the entries in `driver where vat='Y'` to then populate a 3rd table, say Vat record to record the total amount of vat?